# Regex for exponential function (e^x)

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check if a string contains something with `e^x` or `e^(any #, including negative)x`, but I can't quite figure it out. Here is what I have tried:

```
if(str.matches("^(e^x)$") || str.matches("^(e^[-?0-9]x)$")){
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

Some examples that would match would be:

```
-3e^x
100e^-x
e^-2x
```

I have referenced [this](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/), but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: `[+|-]?\d*e\^[+|-]?\d*x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unescaped `^` matches the beginning of a string. If you use it inside the regex pattern and do not specify the multiline flag, the pattern will always fail since a start of a string cannot appear in the middle of it.

You need to escape the `^` and with `matches()` you do not need anchors. Also, you can just use `?` (one or zero occurrences) or `*` (zero or more occurrences) quantifiers:

```
if(str.matches("-?[0-9]*e\\^-?[0-9]*x"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rI0yB1/1)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that ^ symbol is for the start of the string and hence if you want to use if only for the symbol at / before it.

Answer (score 2):

`-?\\d*\\.?\\d*e\\^-?\\d*\\.?\\d*x` works for floating point numbers as well.

It matches:

- `e^x`
- `-3e^x`
- `100e^-x`
- `e^-2x`
- `-0.1e^2x`
- `-0.1e^0.2x`

Answer (score 0):

your required regex will be like this 
the basic problem is with your regex is ^ sign 
you have to ignore ^ as like start match use \^

**e\^-?\d*?**

and your code will be

```
if(str.matches("e\^\-?\d*?") ){
            System.out.println("match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-?\\d*\\.?\\d*e\\^-?\\d*\\.?\\d*x
```

Answer (score -1):

It should work for     `-?\\d*e\\^-?\\d*x`

-? matches the character - literally, Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time

\d* match a digit [0-9] Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times

e matches the character e literally (case sensitive)

\^ matches the character ^ literally

-? matches the character - literally, Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time

\d* match a digit [0-9] Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times